# using non-greedy qualifiers in regular expression '*?'

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a python 2.7 based program that takes input from a user (either as text file) or directly on the command prompt. I have to then verify the input to make sure that it is in the correct format (and reformat using code if needed).

Ideal inputs from user will be words separated by commas like
 `"blade, coffeen, cardiac".`
But i wanted to put a check to allow inputs in the format
`"blade, coffeen,    , cardiac"`
`"blade,,cofeen,cardiac"`
`"blade coffeen cardiac"` etc.

This means I probably have to use a non-greedy qualifier like `*?`. Though I know basic regular expressions, this particular one `*?` is a bit unclear. Right now I am using `input_string.split(',')` followed by a `input_string.split(' ')` to account for the various scenarios, but somehow it feels too unpythonic and messy. I also wonder if there are scenarios that I haven't thought of and will break the code in production.

Looking on the internet, this link https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html does a pretty good job of explaining how `.*?` works, and I think if I use `[, ]*?`, that can solve my problem.

My question is:
1. Can I use `[, ]*?` in my case, to account for the three possible scenarios for inputs that I described above?
As I mentioned, I am using `string.split(',')` after the validation anyways followed by a `string.split(' ')` , but a regular expression check will make it cleaner. In any case, I would love to understand how exactly the `[, ]*?` will behave if used.

Comment: Use [Regex101](https://regex101.com) to test your RegEx. [Your Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lF4zL7/1)

Comment: What happens when the input is `thomas edison, leonardo da vinci` ?

Comment: @Druzion Thank you for that Regex test link. it's awesome.

Comment: @SQLPolice yes. that is the next piece I have to figure out. but that has even more complexity since a lot of users are big fans of unicode, prefer fancy player names and are located globally. I am going to have to create some kind of unicode to character mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `[, ]*?` if it is part of a larger regular expression. And you may as well use `re.split()` in your case and avoid having to use `str.split()` separately.

However, you don't *need* to use the `?` greediness modifier, as you are explicitly checking for *words separated by spaces and commas*. The word characters won't themselves ever match the `[, ]*` set. In fact, greedy matching will improve performance of the match here, as the regular expression will pick up all spaces and commas in one go, rather than just one at a time and then having to check if the rest of your pattern matches right after the first space or comma, then the next space or comma, etc.

So, the following *works*, but removing the `?` makes the expression work *better*:

```
>>> import re
>>> test = "blade, coffeen,    , cardiac"
>>> re.search('blade[, ]*?coffeen[, ]*?cardiac', test)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x100758c60>
>>> re.search('blade[, ]*coffeen[, ]*cardiac', test)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1026101d0>
```

You'll notice the problem when you try to use `re.split()` and only use `[, ]*?` as the pattern:

```
>>> import re
>>> test = "blade, coffeen,    , cardiac"
>>> re.split('[, ]*?', test)
['blade, coffeen,    , cardiac']
```

When splitting by `[, ]*?`, even a *zero width string* (an empty string) matches the expression, and `re.split()` won't split on empty strings alone. Being non-greedy, a zero-width string satisfied the test, and the regex engine won't go looking for more.

You could modify it to using `+?` (match at least one, or more):

```
>>> re.split('[, ]+?', test)
['blade', '', 'coffeen', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'cardiac']
```

Now you get a whole series of empty strings in-between, because those separate the various spaces and commas between the words.

Only when I remove the non-greedy modifier will it correctly split out your options into a list, because now *all* whitespace and commas between the words match and are used to split on:

```
>>> re.split('[, ]*', test)
['blade', 'coffeen', 'cardiac']
```

So don't fear greediness, not when matching a very specific subset of characters where the boundaries can't be confused or over-matched.

Comment: that is perfect. great explanation and good pointers on the empty string scenario. I didnt know about the re.split option that can use a regular expression to split strings. Really appreciate the solution and the tips.